# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()'

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to build a Linq to Entities query that joins a table with a foreign key column of string and the related table ID has an integer ID.  I know, I know, whoever designed the database schema screwed up, but unfortunately for whatever reasons, I can't change the database schema in this case.

Here is the error I get:

***LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.***

Here is the linq (to Entities) statement that causes it:

```
var query = from p in db.QBPOes
            join j in db.tblJobManagements on p.CustJob equals j.JobID
            join s in db.tblSuppliers on p.VendorID equals s.SupplierID.ToString()
            where p.ID == poID
            select new 
            {
                p.ID,
                p.Date,
                p.VendorID,
                p.FirstName,
                p.LastName,
                s.SupplierWorkPhone,
                s.SupplierFaxNumber,
                p.CompanyName,
            };
```

I am joining these tables because I want to get the supplier phone and fax number.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to cast p.VendorID into an `integer` you can use this workaround. The generated SQL might not be pretty, but it should work, unless p.VendorID can not be cast into an integer

```
var query = from p in db.QBPOes
            let vendorId = db.QBPOes.Select(x => p.VendorID).Cast<int>().FirstOrDefault()
            join j in db.tblJobManagements on p.CustJob equals j.JobID
            join s in db.tblSuppliers on vendorId equals s.SupplierID
            where p.ID == poID
            select new 
            {
                p.ID,
                p.Date,
                p.VendorID,
                p.FirstName,
                p.LastName,
                s.SupplierWorkPhone,
                s.SupplierFaxNumber,
                p.CompanyName,
            };
```

It might be better to cast s.SupplierID to string, so you would rearrange your query like so

```
var query = from s in db.tblSuppliers
            let supplierID = db.tblSuppliers.Select(x => s.SupplierID).Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault()
            join p in db.QBPOes on supplierID equals p.VendorID
            join j in db.tblJobManagements on p.CustJob equals j.JobID
            where p.ID == poID
            select new 
            {
              p.ID,
              p.Date,
              p.VendorID,
              p.FirstName,
              p.LastName,
              s.SupplierWorkPhone,
              s.SupplierFaxNumber,
              p.CompanyName,
            };
```

Comment: +1 for pointing two alternatives, one of which probably has a better execution plan.

Comment: Thanks Aducci!  I tried your first solution and it worked like a charm.